# I installed ObjectAid UML but I can't see the class relatioship lines

Tags: uml, objectaid

I just installed ObjectAid UML Explorer but I have a minor problem.
I can't see the class relationship lines. I know there is a line because I can see the line from png file.but somehow it's not seen.
How can I fix this problem? Please, help!

[image]

this is a png file.

[image]

Comment: That dependency seems to be useless in any case.

Comment: Yeah, but my classmates who wrote the same code could see the line with this same java class. So I am wondering whether installation error or some kind of bug.